# Angular Router with keywords in url

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up  path  for the following combination of urls

- /red-cars-for-sale-fl
- /used-cars-for-sale-ca
- /new-cars-for-sale-ga
- /fast-cars-for-sale-fl and so on.

All these    urls  should match  one component  CarSaleComponent. Similarly, boats-for-sale set of urls should instantiate BoatSaleComponent and so on

```
 { path: ':param1', component: CarSaleComponent }, 
 { path: ':param1', component: BoatSaleComponent }, 
 { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
```

This does not work     because /contact will also match the first path and  instantiate CarSaleComponent.  I am using a workaround as

```
 { path: 'cars/:param1', component: CarSaleComponent }, 
 { path: 'boats/:param1', component: BoatSaleComponent },
 { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
```

is it possible to match the path based on  "cars-for-sale"  or "boats-for-sale" sub-strings  ?

Answer (score -1):

There can be two ways of doing this.

1. You can pass the params in the URL to tell the sale for `boat/car`. Based on the input you show/hide the `CarSaleComponent`/`BoatSaleComponent`. The bad side is if you add more items for sale you might need to add a config which enables/disables the list of component.
2. You can create routes for every item `item-for-sale` and pass the necessary information in the query.

```
 { path: 'car-for-sale', component: CarSaleComponent }, 
 { path: 'boat-for-sale', component: BoatSaleComponent }, 
 { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
```

You can also create a sale module and lazy load it when the user try to access this specific information. You can also create child routes for different items under it and route them accordingly.

Also, the routes match is based on the how they are define in the routing from top to bottom. So, always put them in the way you match root `/` in the end.

Comment: Question is how to configure paths for given urls  based  on sub-string match. It's not about finding a work around with query params. I already know a few workarounds